Crontab isn't changing my wallpaper
#My crontab -e (conf)-
 * * * * * /home/barmanji/random_wallpaper.sh

#My random_wallpaper.sh (conf)-
#!/bin/bash

nitrogen --set-zoom-fill --random ~/Downloads/ColorWall

#I am new to linux and specially i3 Windows Manager. and i am unable to figure this out that why my wallpaper isn't changing after a set time interval, the script is running fine. Help me please.

add absolute path in front ofnitrogen and the ~ is not going to get replaced by ./home/barmanji from cron.

I don't see why ~ wouldn't be replaced by the expected path - provided the OP used their personal crontab (crontab -e not sudo crontab -e for example). Perhaps this is a case of nitrogen not being able to connect to the display server from outside of the desktop environment (no DISPLAY or DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)?

For some reason after restarting 10-20 times, it started working , have no clue how and I don't want to mess it up, I have other crontab scripts running as well but they never gave me any issue, this nitrogen is just beyond my mental!
